# session times out despite activity in an app built with Spring boot and embedded jetty

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-jetty, spring-saml, httpsession

We have the following:

- Java 8 web app developed with Spring Boot and embedded Jetty.
- The UI for the app is built using react.
- The backend exposes multiple REST APIs via Jersey.
- The authentication is done using SAML with Okta as the IDP. We use spring-security-saml-core for SAML authentication.
- The Java app is fronted by Nginx for SSL termination but this issue is reproducible without Nginx too.

The issue we have been noticing is that the user session times-out after the session timeout time despite user activity. Following is an excerpt of the application.properties related to session and JSESSIONID cookie:

```
    # Session #
    server.session.cookie.domain=domain.example.com
    server.session.cookie.http-only=true
    server.session.cookie.max-age=-1
    server.session.cookie.name=JSESSIONID
    server.session.cookie.path=/
    server.session.cookie.secure=true
    server.session.persistent=false
    server.session.timeout=900
    server.session.tracking-modes=cookie

    # Custom #
    auth.cookie-max-age=900
```

The `cookie-mag-age` above dictates the lifespan of other cookies we create to store other user details, e.g user id. Following code gets called when Okta sends back the assertion on valid auth. This is a custom class extended from `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response,
        final Authentication authentication)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    Object credentials = authentication.getCredentials();
    if (credentials instanceof SAMLCredential) {
        SAMLCredential samlCredential = (SAMLCredential) credentials;
        NameID nameId = samlCredential.getNameID();
        if (nameId != null) {
            String nameIdValue = nameId.getValue();
            UserDetail userDetail = userManager.getUserByName(nameIdValue, false);
            if(userDetail != null) {
                session.setAttribute(Constants.SESSION_USERID_FIELD, userDetail.getId());
                String token = csrfTokenManager.getTokenFromSession(request);
                if(token == null) {
                    token = csrfTokenManager.generateAndSaveToken(request, response);
                    response.addHeader(CsrfTokenManager.TOKEN_HEADER_NAME, token);
                }
                Cookie idCookie = AuthUtil.createCookie(
                        Constants.SESSION_USERID_FIELD,
                        userDetail.getId(),
                        appConfig.getCookieMaxAge(), true);
                response.addCookie(idCookie);
            }
        }
    }

    getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response,
            appConfig.getAuthSuccessRedirectUrl());
}
```

We call the REST APIs from Javascript using isomorphic fetch as follows:

```
export const fetchAllProjects = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestAllProjects())
        return fetch(`/rest/private/v1/projects`, {
            credentials: 'same-origin'
        })
            .then(errorMessageUtil.handleErrors)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => dispatch(receiveAllProjects(json)))
            .catch(error => errorMessageUtil.dispatchError(error, dispatch, appActions.displayBadRequestMessage))
    }
}
```

The `credentials: 'same-origin'`, sends all the cookies to the backend including the JESESSIONID and the other cookies set above. We have an authentication filter that checks for valid session and not sends 401

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
    if(session == null)  {
        this.sendUnauthorizedResponse(httpServletResponse);
    } else {
        String userIdFromCookie = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if(Constants.SESSION_USERID_FIELD.equals(cookie.getName())) {
                userIdFromCookie = cookie.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        String userId = (String)session.getAttribute(Constants.SESSION_USERID_FIELD);
        if(userIdFromCookie != null && userId != null
                && userId.equals(userIdFromCookie)) {
            HeaderMapRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
            requestWrapper.addHeader(Constants.USERID_HEADER_NAME, userId);
            chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, httpServletResponse);
        } else {
            this.sendUnauthorizedResponse(httpServletResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure, we are not doing something right because the timeout time for the session is for the inactivity.

One other question is, do calls to the REST APIs qualify as valid activity for session time-out to extend?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem with my logic. The code above tries to get the userId from the cookie and the userId from the session and then compare and if not matched, redirect the user to login.

The issue was the timeout time for the session and the cookie expiry time, `auth.cookie-max-age=900`, were same so even though the session was active because of activity, the cookie was getting expired and userId values didn't match.

My approach is to increase the max age of the cookie to a bigger value, so UI can keep sending the cookies with valid values and if the session really expires due to inactivity, its the userId value from the session that will be null and the user will need to re-login.